# Verify Token exists inside database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Basically, I want to verify posted token that exists in the database

I got 1 table named users, username, password, email, and uploadkey column

Basically, I am trying to check the posted uploadkey against all available other uploadKeys in the database to see if any of them match.

What ive tried so far that didnt work:

```
$uploadKey = $_POST['key'];
$isKeyValid = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uploadkey = ?");
$isKeyValid->execute([$uploadKey]);
$count = $isKeyValid->rowCount();

if ($count < 1) {
    die('error,e-401');
}
```

And i also tried:

```
$uploadKey = $_POST['key'];
$isKeyValid = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uploadkey = ?");
$isKeyValid->execute([$uploadKey]);

if (!$isKeyValid) {
    die('error,e-401');
}
```

None of these work the way I want them to, and I was hoping anyone on here maybe had a solution on how to loop thru all database tokens correctly so it can see if it matches any in the DB and then auth the user to upload.

Comment: Can you please expand on _"None of these work the way i want it to"_? What's happening that isn't supposed to? Or not happening, but is supposed to?

Comment: Why doesn't this work? Have you checked the database directly? is the key you are testing with in there at all?

Comment: Yes it is in the database, ive checked 5 times over n over, and the key is in one of the users table, but now when i upload with any key that doesnt even exist in the db it allows them to upload anyway without the key being correct on both of them....

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? Like dumping values to ensure they are what you expect them to be?